# Displaying Nearest Enemy Health - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, logic

Im trying to make a system in which my UI will display the nearest enemys health and sprite. I have already got the panels and UI working to display the Player health but im unsure as to how to display whichever enemy has came close or within range of the player.

** The game is running around but coming within range of an enemy triggers combat**

The below code can display a characters health if I place the script on the player/enemy. Im grabbing two variables from Bolt also.

I can display a single enemy no problem in this way.  But if i put 50 enemies in one scene it means I have to manually load the panels/UI for each enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Bolt;
using Ludiq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthAndCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Slider healthBarSlider;
    public float health;
    private bool inCombat;
    private GameObject nearestEnemy;
    public GameObject healthBarCanvas;
    public GameObject bestFighterUI;

    private void Start()
    {
        healthBarSlider.value = health;
        bestFighterUI.SetActive(false);

    }
    void Update()
    {
        health = (float)Variables.Object(player).Get("Health");
        inCombat = (bool)Variables.Object(player).Get("combat");
        nearestEnemy = (GameObject)Variables.Object(player).Get("nearestEnemy");
        
        if (inCombat)
        {
            healthBarCanvas.SetActive(true);
            bestFighterUI.SetActive(true);
            healthBarSlider.value = health;
        }
        else {
            healthBarCanvas.SetActive(false);
            bestFighterUI.SetActive(false);
        }
        
    }
```

Im thinking -

-Load the scene.
-Find all objects called enemy and register their health in a list.
-Work out distance from player to each enemy.
-If player in combat, display nearest enemy to player.

I just dont know should I have an overall scene manager for code or have scripts for detection on each player.